# String.Split() removes leading zeros

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I am trying to split my current applications version number, but is removes the leading zeros.

How do i change my split to not remove the leading zeros.

Getting the currentVersionNo:

```
startUpAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```

So for testing:

```
string versionNo = "7.01.7000.0";

string[] versionInfo = versionNo.Split('.');
```

This produces:

```
7
1 //Here i need it to be 01
7000
0
```

And i need it to NOT remove the leading zero. How do i achieve this?

Maybe there is a better solution using regex?

Comment: Your sample code wouldn't compile - 7.01.7000.0 isn't a string literal.

Comment: ... and after you add double quotes around - it works as expected.

Comment: (I strongly suspect the problem has *nothing* to do with String.Split...)

Comment: "Here i **need** it to be 01" -- why do you want your code to rely on insignificant character?

Comment: What actually produces the result you mention ? Did you check the contents of the array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `System.Version` isn't an arbitrary string - it's four integers. Leading zeroes are irrelevant, so not included when converting back to a string. That's where you're losing information - not in `String.Split`. You can see this very easily:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Version version = new Version("7.01.7000.0");
        Console.WriteLine(version); // 7.1.7000.0
    }
}
```

Basically, your plan is fundamentally flawed, and you should change your design. You shouldn't be *trying* to represent a version of "7.01.7000.0" to start with.

Additionally, you should take a step back and think about your diagnostic procedure: what made you think that `String.Split` was to blame here? Why wasn't your first step looking at the result of `startUpAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString()`?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I overlooked that `Application.Current.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()` returns `7.1.7000.0`.

Comment: @Willem: Sure - I'm just suggesting that you do a bit of reflection on your diagnostic approach that made you overlook that. For example, the code in your question *doesn't* produce the output you say it does, so presumably you didn't run that. Looking back on this particular example may help you improve your approach for future problems.